# how do i stop repeating answers in this?

Tags: c++

i am trying to code a family feud type game and I want to know how do I stop repeated answers? like in this code i could keep writing "bugs" and the loop would just carry on.

```
void f()
{
    int y=0;
    string q[17];
    string ans1[4];
    ans1[0]= "bears";
    ans1[1]="bugs";
    ans1[2]= "snakes";
    ans1[3]="skunks";
    string ans;
    int sum=0;
    q[0]="Name something you try to avoid when camping in the woods.";
    cout << q[0] << endl;
    for (int a=0; a<7; a++)
    {
        int b;
        getline(cin,ans);
        if (ans==ans1[0]||ans==ans1[1]||ans==ans1[2]||ans==ans1[3])
        {
           if (ans==ans1[0])
           {
               b=42;
            cout << "SURVEY SAYS " <<  b << "! Good Job! " << endl; sum=sum+b;
           }
           else if (ans==ans1[1])
           {
               b=33;
            cout << "SURVEY SAYS " <<  b << "! Nice one man! " << endl; sum=sum+b;
           }
           else if (ans==ans1[2])
            {
                b=20;
           cout <<"SURVEY SAYS " << b << "! Fantastic man!"<< endl; sum=sum+b;
            }

            else if (ans==ans1[3])
                {
                    b=5;
                    cout << "SURVEY SAYS " << b << "! You Got it!" << endl; sum=sum+b;
                }
        }
        else if (ans!=ans1[0]&&ans!=ans1[1]&&ans!=ans1[2]&&ans!=ans1[3])
        {
               cout << "YOU GOT THIS ONE WRONG! "<< endl; y++;
       if (y==3) { cout << "LOOOOSER" << endl; break;}
        }
    }
    cout << " your total score for
```

this round is " << sum << endl;
}

Comment: if you think of your answers as a list of "valid answers not yet guessed,"  when a valid answer is guessed, it must be removed from the list.  either put each answer in a container (vector per jack deeth) and remove each guessed one, or somehow mark each guessed answer and not test for it again.  the test for correct answers should loop over the list of valid answers; the existing test will not work well.  another point: the 'else if' test is not helpful: the outer if tests to see if any answer is correct; if this test fails, the else must be true, so no need to do all of the != tests

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to keep a list (I'd recommend `std::vector`) of all the accepted answers. Then, when given a new answer, you'd need to check it isn't in the list.

Alternatively, for each answer, have an `wasUsed` variable which you check when the answer is given and set after an answer is accepted.